# EJB from spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ejb, distributed-transactions

i need to make multiple call to an EJB web service and maintain transactionality between the multiple ejb invocation, from a spring boot application not deployed on an application server, is this possible,
if yes, someone can explain to me how to make this work?

Thanks, Giuseppe

Comment: There is too little information to answer this. Without knowing which server is being used or what you already tried, this is impossible to answre.

Comment: Take a look at this link : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-ejb

Comment: Hi, the server is websphere application server